# What does gdb -i=mi mean?

Tags: linux, emacs, gdb, emacs24

When starting gdb from emacs, emacs says that gdb should be started as

```
gdb -i=mi
```

The option **-i** is not defined in the gdb man page. If gdb is invoked from the command line with option **-i=mi**, it works. So it must be specific to gdb. Where is the documentation for the -i option?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`gdb -i=mi` is equivalent to `gdb --interpreter=mi`.

In short, `--interpreter=mi` makes `gdb` present a machine-oriented text interface rather than the human-oriented command prompt you get without it. Emacs's `gud` buffer parses the output from this interface and presents something resembling the normal gdb interface to you.

The `--interpreter` flag is documented [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Mode-Options.html#Mode-Options), and the `GDB/MI` interface is documented [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI.html). That `-i` is an alias for `--interpreter` is mentioned in passing [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Interpreters.html).